# Putting method with loop doesnt work

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to inserting the values of counter into an array called numpay.Unfortunately nothing happens.Where's my mistake?Here's what i tried below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example-1</title>

</head>

<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>
        function validateForm() {

            var months=(principal+principal*interestrate*0.01)/monthlypayment;
            var numpay = new Array(months);
            for(var i=0;i<=months-1;i++)
                {
                numpay.push(i);
                text += numpay[i] + "<br>";

            }
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

    }
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are there any console errors?

Comment: Not any console errors.Nothing has written i'll share full code of the project

Comment: You have an extra curly brace a the bottom. By creating an array like that you are saying to create months number of undefined. Then you are pushing to the end of months.length array. You also need to initialize text with months `var months = 12, text;`.

Comment: We don't need the full code of the project, just a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) By creating an array like that (`new Array(12)`) you are saying to create 12 `undefined` entries in the array. Then you are pushing to the end of the array.

2.) You also need to initialize text with months `var months = 12, text;`.

```
var months = 12, text;
var numpay = new Array(months);
for(var i=1; i<=months; i++){
    numpay[i] = i;
    text += numpay[i] + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

This will still give you undefined at index 0 but I will leave that for you to work out. But doing `numpay[i] = i` will overwrite your `undefined` that was created with the array.

Comment: text=" "; solved the undefined element problem.Thanx very much

Answer (score 1):

### Fixing existing problems

As others have pointed out, something like this should work:

```js
var months = 12;
var numpay = []; // just as easy
var text = "";

for (var i = 1; i <= months; i++) {
  numpay.push(i);
  text += numpay[i - 1] + "<br/>";
}

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo">(empty)</p>
```

### Enhancing your skills

Although you're combining them in your `for`-loop, you're doing two separate things here: filling out the months, and creating the text you want to add to the DOM.

There's a lot to be said for one bit of code doing only one thing.  You could write a reusable `range` function which uses more modern JS techniques to give you a numeric integer range between two values.  So

```
const range = (lo, hi) => [...new Array(hi - lo + 1)].map((_, i) => i + lo);
```

Using that, you can create your `months` variable by calling this function:

```
const months = range(1, 12);
```

Then, with this array, you can use [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to combine the values into the text you would like:

```
const text = months.join('<br/>')
```

And that leads to a nicer bit of code:

```js
const range = (lo, hi) => [...new Array(hi - lo + 1)].map((_, i) => i + lo);

const months = range(1, 12);

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = months.join('<br/>');
```

```html
<p id="demo">(empty)</p>
```

If you need that `text` variable for something additional, then just assign it as the result of the join, and then assign the `innerHTML` to it.

Obviously that `range` function is unnecessary.  You could just write `const months =  [...new Array(12)].map((_, i) => i + 1);`.  But thinking in terms of such abstractions often lets you write cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in JS are zero-based, so if you do `.push(i)` with `i === 1`, the value `1` goes into the slot for `numpay[0]`.

And then to access that item, you must use `numpay[i-1]`.

**Another thing** is that you seem to have forgotten to declare and initialize `text` before the loop starts. You need to do that, if not then the variable only exists inside the loop body (and loses its value each time the loop body ends).

Demo:

```js
var months = 12;
var numpay = []; // just as easy
var text = "- ";

for (var i = 1; i <= months; i++) {
  numpay.push(i);
  text += numpay[i - 1] + " - ";
}
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate an array with a parameter like this:

```
var numpay = Array(12);
```

it results in an array with 12 undefined elements.  When you push a new item, it will be placed in the 13th slot.

Instead, just do this:

```
var text = "";
var months=12;
var numpay = [];
for(var i=1;i<=months;i++)
{
    numpay.push(i);
    text += numpay[i-1] + "<br>";  //use i-1 here, not i

}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

The result is:

```
"1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>11<br>12<br>"
```